# weird issue with the Homestead

Tags: git, bash, laravel, git-bash, homestead

I have installed homestead on a windows machine using the Git Bash cl, everything is well configured , but when I run "homestead up" and ssh to my vagrant machine I see some weird characters beside folders names (see picture) . when I run unix commands "ls" as an example .. it behaves abnormally so that the index is still at the same line while the files and folders are listen under . and when I try to open the domain name I configured , I get : "No input file specified". Have you ever been in such a situation?

[image]

Comment: Those are ANSI color escape sequences. It appears that your terminal emulator doesn't support those escape sequences. Try Googling or playing with your application's configurations.

Comment: I use putty when connecting to homestead, it supports the color codes.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Conosle2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) in combination with [Ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) which adds ANSI color support to windows.

- Install Console2
- Copy `ansicon` into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Console2\ansicon`
- use `ansicon -i` to install (`ansicon -u` to uninstall). Install x86 version for use with git bash.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer , I followed your instructions , but when I run homestead ssh in GItbash , I get "ANSICON: cmd.exe: unsupported process." but I get to ssh to the server . The problem is that  git bash now somehow won't work .. I can't run any command in Git .. I can't even type any :/

Comment: Did you use `ansicon -i` within the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Console2\ansicon` folder? Make sure u use the x86 version even if you are on a 64 bit machine. You need to use Console2 instead of Git bash to make the colors work. Here is how to integrate Git bash into Console2: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/04/05/integrating-the-git-bash-into-console/

Comment: Ok , now I understand ... I now have a git bash tab in console2 , but when I run "ls" or "homestead ssh" I get : /bin/env: sh:no file or directory

Comment: Are you sure that this is a problem of ansicon? You can test this by uninstalling `ansicon -u` within the ansicon folder. Then test if `ls` or `homestead ssh` works. If so then it is an ansicon error if not there is another problem not related to ansicon.

Comment: ok , when I uninstall it and run these 2 commands in console2 , i get the same error.. But they work fine on git bash

Comment: Hm this sounds like the git bash didn't properly integrate into console2. Try this as shell path for your console2 git bash tab: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"` then open a new git bash tab in console2 and try again. If this dosn't work I have no clue why as exactly this config works at 2 machines here with ansicon installed.